# some javascript/css files not available in public directory on heroku but work locally

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

My nodejs app runs fine locally and all resources are available.

When uploaded to heroku it cannot find 4  css/js resources, where as everything else is loading fine locally and on heroku.

I have tried:

Checking the remote heroku directory to make sure the missing files exist within my public/vendor directory - they do.

I tried changing the static path for 'production' but this seems to have no impact.

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if ('development' == env) {
    mongoose.connect(configDB.devurl); // connect to our database
    app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
}

if ('production' == env) {
    process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
    mongoose.connect(configDB.produrl); // connect to our database
    app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/public'));
}
```

Any ideas? I am well and truly confused. This is what the heroku log shows when I just point directly at the file:

```
2016-01-03T08:58:05.943206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/vendor/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.css" host=sleepy-refuge-6282.herokuapp.com request_id=47bd858a-8dd6-4fe3-b99c-33d2f135d719 fwd="94.0.192.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2381ms status=404 bytes=246
```

I am using express 4

Comment: Does the filenames case match?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very experienced with nodejs/ express - how do I check that?

Comment: you mean the actual case? That seems to be it, what the heck! It works when I change everything to lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are developing your application on OS X or Windows which filesystem isn't case sensitive.

Heroku Dynos are actually linux containers with case sensitive file system, so filename's case should match there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that on heroku the files need to have the same case as the underlying folder structure in the app. It doesn't have an impact on my localhost but it does when pushed to Heroku for some reason.